# Loading composer packages without using composer (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm wondering how I would be able to load PHP packages without using composer to do so.

I'm unable to use composer as I'm using shared hosting, which imposes limitations like being unable to install composer due to a **heavily** jailed shell.

While there are certain packages which allow for the loading of a package with `require_once('package/Autoloader.php');`, i.e. Braintree & Twig.

However, not all packages can be loaded like this, example being, 
[Pug-PHP](https://github.com/pug-php/pug]), which only includes installation with composer.

Can anyone help me load composer packages without composer?

Comment: can you run `php` command  ? at your server. may be like this `/user/bin/php5 test.php`

Comment: Yes, I am able to use the php command.

Comment: check this command line installation :  https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: run given command.

Comment: ```Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The suhosin.executor.include.whitelist setting is incorrect
Add the following to the end of your `php.ini` or suhosin.ini (Example path [for Debian]: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini):
    suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar 

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: /opt/alt/php56/etc/php.ini
If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use -d multiple times```

Comment: Though, this doesn't answer my question; My question was how to install packages without composer, not how to install it.

Comment: Do you need to install them or just make them work on production environment ? Because in the latter case copying vendor folder directly to hosting will work.

Comment: That sounds promising, I'll definitely have to look into it more, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to Packages being a dependency of the composer management system. Replicate the ENV locally and use @MichalGallovic 's suggestion.

There is also the option of git clone every package and dependency from their respective source repos; but at that point you will hate yourself.

Is the option of using a host that are not as strict an option?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://php-download.com/ They have a number of packages ready to go that will no longer need Composer. It finds and creates all required folders and creates a zips it for download. Saves me hours of drama.

Comment: needs paid subscription